# Semantic ui dropdown menu doesn't work with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I want to have a dropdown menu on mobile and tablet only but it doesn't seem to be working when I click the menu button.

navbar.html.erb:

```
<div class="ui inverted right menu mobile only tablet only grid">
    <div class="ui dropdown icon teal item">
      <i class="align big justify icon"></i>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">
          Profile
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          Friends
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          Log out
        </div>
        <div class="ui fluid search item">
          <div class="ui icon input">
            <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search friends...">
            <i class="search icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="results">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

navbar.js:

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown();
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require semantic-ui
//= require semantic-ui/modal
//= require semantic-ui/dropdown
//= require semantic-ui/tab
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you verify that your JS is being included properly in your page? Any JS errors? If the Jquery selector works, semantic should also work assuming you placed it in the correct location.

Comment: I have other code in the js file that changes the color of button `$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });`and it is working. so the file is included fine.